# Im trying to get user online status in Android Studio but the following line gives me an error

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to get the user online status, but the error shown below is not allowing it.
The line containing the error is:

```
.setValue(new User(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),"Online"));
```

How do I solve and why does it happen? Please help me.
Code:

```java
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class))
    {
        currentUserRef.onDisconnect().removeValue();// Delete old value
        counterRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .setValue(new User(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),"Online"));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: `the error` which error?

Comment: this one Error:(71, 39) error: constructor User in class User cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String,String,Uri
found: String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: as it says - there is no constructor which accepts 2 `String` arguments in `User` class.